# Is there a speech to text API or some "hack" by which I can use Google's speech to text facilities?

Tags: speech-recognition, google-api

I think Google's speech to text facilities (Google Voice automatic transcription of voicemail, automatic captioning of videos on YouTube etc) are quite impressive.

I did look to see whether Google has made it available through an API and it seems they haven't (not that I blame them!). A cloud computing service providing speech to text functionality would be pretty cool though.

Is there some sort of "hack" that I can use to access the speech to text. My architecture basically comes down to this - a short 15-20 second wav/mp3/other clip as the input, output is plaintext.

Any ideas people?

Comment: What platform?  The related questions (look down and to the right on this page) might provide some insight.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of speech to text APIs.  Just because Google doesn't make theirs available, it doesn't mean you're out of luck.

Here is a good one for C#.  You can search for others for your platform if it's not .NET.

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/

I am currently trying to implement the API in PHP.

--Seth

Comment: Seth - did you ever get this API implemented? Would you be interested in sharing on Github?

Comment: I did not; I got Google to recognize text in the audio clips that I posted to the URL in that article though.  The reason that I gave up is because my application was using mp3 files and Google's server would only accept *.flac files.

Answer (score 1):

It's available in HTML5, via Chrome 8 or Opera:
https://docs.google.com/View?id=dcfg79pz_5dhnp23f5&pli=1

Google speech technologies are also accessible via the Android API on an Android phone.

The other products out there, like Sphinx, are speech recognition engines that work best in specific domains, not "unconstrained" speech-to-text.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more recent, more "official" version of Peter Moffatt's suggestion:

http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html

And Google's related announcement:

http://chrome.blogspot.com/2011/03/talking-to-your-computer-with-html5.html

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the following implementation using C# - I used the Mike Pultz link.

https://github.com/seigneur/Voice-Biometrics
I used Sox to convert into flac, created a small SOX script to split it into chunks.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want google's output... Here is a Hack method

Have you thought about a making phone submission engine? 
Essentially it calls your google voicemail... plays the mp3.

Snag the output via https://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/

Better answers present.